# How to Choose What is Included in Table of Contents for ePub Book

Tags: scrivener, table-of-contents

Right now, Scrivener only includes folders at `Level 1+` in the generated ePub table of contents. How do I also tell it to include text at `Level 3+` as part of the table of contents?

I'm not seeing an option to edit the documents included in the table of contents. I would expect one in the `Formatting` tab of the Compile options.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a way to adjust that.

Instead of using the compiler-generated HTML TOC, you can create your own HTML TOC. Two steps:

1. In the Layout section of the compiler, deselect "Generate HTML table of contents."
2. Add a Contents document to your project, with the titles of each item you want to include. Format each title as you like, and make each title link to the appropriate folder or text document.

Note: This will affect only the HTML table of contents in the body of your epub file. It will not affect the NCX file that many readers use to build their own navigation links. I cannot see a way to influence what goes into the NCX file other than using folders to indicate titles. (Or editing it by hand afterward.)

Also, I cannot see a way to convince the compiler to generate a hierarchical TOC.

This is one of the reasons I don't use Scrivener to create my epubs. :-( Scrivener is very good at producing nice, clean epub files, but, alas, it does not give me quite enough control over the output.

Comment: What software do you use to create epubs?

Comment: For a while I used Jutoh. I found its usability awkward, but it gives lots of control. Now I use a homegrown thing, built on Pandoc (to convert Scrivener's RTF files to markdown), Jekyll (to convert markdown to HTML), and Ruby (to compile epubs from HTML files). If you're interested it's on GitHub ( https://github.com/dhemery/jpub ), but be aware that the git repo is a little out of date, and I offer ABSOLUTELY ZERO support. Lots of folks use Calibre or Sigil. I avoided Sigil because it looked as if its developers were abandoning it. But now I think new developers have taken up the reins.

Answer (score 1):

For simple epub docs, I use Calibre to generate the TOC for me. It doesn't matter whether or not you have Scrivener generate the TOC. I end up deleting it anyway. In Calibre, if you go to the 'Edit Book' function in the main toolbar, you can select 'Edit table of contents' in the following toolbar.

From there, I select 'Generate TOC from major headings' and it populates the left column. You can select it from all heading if you wish. Then, you can choose to delete unwanted items, as well as adjust the nesting of them (either making them all equal, or breaking up your chapters). You can also rename the TOC items to whatever you want. Hit 'OK', then save the document. If you try to close the window, it will prompt you to save.

That should provide your new TOC, which works in iBooks (and probably others).